# Apache listen all domains

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

My web project need new mirrors domain each weeks.
The website is able to buy himself the domain with a Registar API.

I'm wundering if there is a way to automatically add the new domain to the virtualhost or config the virtualhost to redirect every domains not present in the virtualhost to a specific `DocumentRoot` ?

If I do that it will work ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mirror.com
    ServerAlias *.mirror.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mirror.com
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public
</VirtualHost>
```